# Not able to handle screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I am trying to handle screen orientation change but the application is crashing, tried searching about the error I am getting in logcat but in vain. Already added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in manifest and trying to override `onConfigurationChanged` but getting same error. 
Error is :

```
12-21 12:04:31.419: E/AndroidRuntime(14573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.click4tab.pustakalpha/com.click4tab.pustakalpha.StartTestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.widget.CompoundButton$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x1. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
```

Which view are we talking about here? 
Posted code on gist: [Link](http://pastie.org/5560323). 
code to  xml: [link](http://pastie.org/5560339)

EDIT: Well, found the problem and took care of it.

Comment: your class to any background process?

Comment: no such is running in background

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Please post your layout XML